# How to generate OR queries in .where() clause using Scala Slick 2.0?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, slick

I want to add two clauses in `where` method of Slick query. I have fllowing code:

```
val users = TableQuery[Users]
val actions = TableQuery[Acts]
val filteredUsers = users.where(.....) // Some condition
val acts = actions.where(_.domain === 10)
val ownerAct = acts.where(_.owner in filteredUsers)
val assigneeAct = acts.where(_.assignee in filteredUsers)
```

I want to fetch actions which belong to either of `assignee` or `ownerer` in filtered users. I want code to be something like this:

```
val users = TableQuery[Users]
val actions = TableQuery[Acts]
val filteredUsers = users.where(.....) // Some condition
val acts = actions.where(_.domain === 10)

val ownerOrAssigneeAct = acts.where(_.owner in filteredUsers).
                                 or(_.assignee in filteredUsers)
```

How can I generate such an OR query in .where() using Scala Slick 2.0?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of things, first to use `in` your query must return something, instead of

```
val filteredUsers = users.where(.....)
```

Should be (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475684/slick-2-0-delete-multiple-rows)):

```
val filteredUsers = users.filter(/* condition */).map(_.id)
```

Assumed that you want to match on ids, then you can compose conditions simply using an anonymous function:

```
val ownerOrAssigneeAct = 
  acts.filter(act => act.domain === 10 && (act.owner in filteredUsers || act.assignee in filteredUsers))
```

Note that I'm not using `where` since it's deprecated, use `filter` instead.

Comment: acts.filter(act => act.domain === 10).filter(act.owner in filteredUsers || act.assignee in filteredUsers))     would be equally fine.